# Apex: Retrieve the URL of a custom object setup detail

Tags: apex, url, describesobject

I'm trying to get a list of all objects and the URLs that lead to their page in the Setup:

[image]

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) I'd expect the below to work but it returns:

> "Expression of type Schema.DescribeSObjectResult has no member named urlDetail"

```
List < Schema.sObjectType > objectSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();

for (Schema.sObjectType obj: objectSchema) {
DescribeSObjectResult describe = obj.getDescribe();

System.debug(describe.urlDetail);

}
```

Comment: you are referencing the SOAP API which isn't always 1:1 with the Apex Describe; Furthermore, `urlDetail` is akin to `URLFOR` and is unrelated to the setup page

Comment: it is because, urldetail is not a member of class DescribeSObjectResult class.

Comment: Schema.DescribeSObjectResult is a different thing than DescribeSObjectResult

Comment: No, the `Schema.` is optional. They are the same.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to do it and the answer below didn't work. I also can't see how Schema.DescribeSObject is different from DescribeSOBject. That seems crazy to me either it is of that class or it isn't. And if they are the same why the docs would say that it would work when it doesn't.

Comment: Let's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41736/retrieve-the-url-of-a-custom-object-setup-detail) about it, then.

Comment: They are the same class, and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) makes no mention of a member named `urlDetail`.  What about my solution did not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually query `EntityDefinition` to get the information you want. However, at least in my sandbox, the value in the `DetailUrl` field is always just `/{ID}`. The Id value itself is just `000000000000000AAA`. Not that useful. But, not to fear, you can use the `DurableId` to build it yourself.

The following works generically for me without issue:

```
public static String getSetupUrl(SObjectType schemaType)
{
    String developerName = String.valueOf(schemaType).replace('__c', '');
    EntityDefinition definition = [
        SELECT DurableId, DetailUrl FROM EntityDefinition
        WHERE DeveloperName = :developerName
    ];

    system.assertEquals('000000000000000AAA', definition.Id);
    system.assertEquals('/{ID}', definition.DetailUrl);

    return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
        '/' + definition.DurableId;
}
```

---

**Note**

You can't use the standard `ApexPages.StandardController.view()` methodology for building the url because the id values are fubar. It just returns `null`.